# How calculate results based in how many times items are in two different lists, but in same position?

Tags: python

I'm capturing data for a grocery shopping program, and need to display the data inserted when the user is done shopping. The values should be shown in the format below:

```
PRODUCT CODE - QUANTITY   -  PRICE
    apple    -    2       -  10.64
   coconut   -    3       -  19.35
   orange    -    1       -  6.45
                      TOTAL: 36.44
```

But I only managed to count and display the TOTAL of the prices of the product codes inserted by the user. This is the code as it stands:

```
product_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'banana', 'coconut']
price_list = [ 5.32 , 6.45 , 2.37 , 5.32, 6.45 ]

bought_product_list = [ ]
bought_price_list = [ ]
quantity = 0

while True:


        
    product_code = input('Enter the product code or END to finnish shopping: ')
    print(' ')

    

    if product_code in product_list:
        product_code_idx = product_list.index(product_code)
        product_price = price_list[product_code_idx]
        
        quantity = int(input('Enter the quantity:'))
            
        bought_product_list.extend([product_code] * quantity)
        bought_price_list.extend([product_price] * quantity)
    

    if product_code == 'END':
        print(' ')
        print('TOTAL: ',sum(bought_price_list))
```

How can I calculate and display the results in the correct format?

Comment: What about the rest of the output? What did you try? You should be able to easily produce the first line.

Comment: I'm very new to programming, couldn't rationalize a way to go past this.

Comment: Ok, but I see you know about `while` loops. Are there any other sorts of loops you know about? There must be some sort of attempt you could try, even by printing some of the variables you have created.

Answer (score 1):

I would create classes.

```
class Product():
    def __init__(self,name,price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

class ShoppingBag():
    def __init__(self):
        self.products = dict()
    
    def add_product(self,product,quantity):
        if(product in self.products):
            self.products[product] += quantity
        else:
            self.products[product] = quantity
    
    def la_cuenta_per_favor(self):
        print("PRODUCT CODE - QUANTITY   -  PRICE")
        tot = 0
        for product,quantity in self.products.items():
            price = quantity *product.price
            print(product.name, " - ", quantity, " - ",price)
            tot += price
        print("                   TOTAL: ",tot)

product_name =""
product_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'banana', 'coconut']
products = [Product('apple',5.32), Product('orange',6.45), Product('watermelon',2.37), Product('banana',5.32), Product('coconut',6.45)]
bag = ShoppingBag()
while(not "END" in product_name ):
    product_name = input('Enter the product code or END to finnish shopping: ')
    print(' ')
    if(product_name in product_list):
        quantity = int(input('Enter the quantity:'))
        bag.add_product(products[product_list.index(product_name)],quantity)
    elif("END" in product_name):
        print(' ')
        bag.la_cuenta_per_favor()
```

Comment: I see what you did. I would do this in normal circumstances, but this may be just too advanced for the OP.